# SWIG Python2.7 warning while building static library resulting in segmentation fault

Tags: python, c, segmentation-fault, makefile, swig

I am trying to build a static library using swig to use a C function in my Python program. I previously compiled the swig command and the other gcc compilation steps where I was using Python2.4.3 . the contents of the Makefile 
 were :

```
all:
 swig -python modlzo.i
 gcc -c -fPIC modlzo.c modlzo_wrap.c -I/usr/include/python2.4 -I/usr/local/include/
 gcc -shared -fPIC -o _modlzo.so  modlzo.o modlzo_wrap.o /usr/local/lib/liblzo.a -Wl,--whole-archive -Wl,--no-whole-archive
```

This was working fine,both the make and the c wrapper for my python program.

Now I have installed another version of python i.e Python2.7.9. So i change the contents of Makefile to:

```
all:
swig -python modlzo.i
gcc -c -fPIC modlzo.c modlzo_wrap.c -I/usr/local/include/python2.7 -I/usr/local/include/
gcc -shared -fPIC -o _modlzo.so  modlzo.o modlzo_wrap.o /usr/local/lib/liblzo.a -Wl,--whole-archive -Wl,--no-whole-archive
```

now when i try to compile this I get the following warning messages which were not there when I use Python2.4.3 path in the Makefile:

```
modlzo_wrap.c: In function ‘SWIG_Python_ConvertFunctionPtr’:
modlzo_wrap.c:2034: warning: initialization discards qualifiers from pointer target type``
modlzo_wrap.c: In function ‘SWIG_AsCharPtrAndSize’:
modlzo_wrap.c:2691: warning: passing argument 3 of ‘PyString_AsStringAndSize’ from incompatible pointer type
modlzo_wrap.c: In function ‘SWIG_Python_FixMethods’:
modlzo_wrap.c:3642: warning: initialization discards qualifiers from pointer target type
```

and this is resulting in segmentation fault when i run my python code.

Any idea why this is happening and what could possibly be done to resolve this?

Comment: What version of SWIG are you using? What does a debugger show?

Comment: SWIG Version 1.3.29

Debugger shows the following Output



`Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
[Switching to Thread 0x41e02940 (LWP 29361)]
0x00002aaab02d5f92 in SWIG_AsCharArray () from /home/sys64/PyMUX2/_modlzo.so`

Comment: I am getting same set of three warnings with 1.3.29, linking with python 2.7.2 .  My code my python code segfaults when it uses function that expects string...  Did you find what was problem?

Comment: I should have just tried latetst version of swig first before I bitch about anything.  With swig v3.0.7, I don't see the problem.